# How many different vacuums are there in the string theory landscape?

Tags: string-theory, vacuum, string-theory-landscape

Different sources give different estimates, from $10 ^{100}$, $10 ^{500}$, $10 ^ {20,000}$, while others write that there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: Does it make a practical difference?

Comment: Note that this number might (a) not be known exactly and (b) be using the word "vacuum" in slightly different contexts.

Comment: @G.Smith There is no difference, just purely mathematical interesting.

Comment: @Charlie Can the number be infinite, or is it just very large? And in what different contexts is it used, besides forms of compactification of curtailed dimensions?

Comment: Which source? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I apologize.
Here estimates are from 10 ^ 200 to 10 ^ 272000
https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0303194
https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.03209

And here it says that there are infinitely many of them
https://motls.blogspot.com/2019/07/vafa-ellis-debate-with-bright-religion.html?m=1

Comment: @G.Smith yes actually. $10^{500}$ would not work for the results of this paper, which requires $> ~10^{1200}$ for anthropic arguments to work. https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.04429

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is that nobody really knows.** It is conjectured that the answer is finite (such as in the case of [elliptically fibered threefolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9305002)), but that is just an speculation. There are no truly physical or mathematical arguments to believe that the answer is not finite.

Answer (score -1):

> How many different vacuums are there in the string theory landscape ?

I never studied string theory, however this question should be bend in slightly different direction.
[Wiki on String-Landscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory_landscape) gives estimates in range $[10^{272,000}; \infty]$. But does it really matters ?

Question should sound like: 
How many different vacuums are there in the string theory landscape **compatible with the Standard Model of particle physics** ? Not so much according [to this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.00009). Add requirement that fermions must be well-defined and other particle physics known limits and you'll get only $10^{15}$ *valid* subspace of string theory solutions.